# Entity Framework with 'Get' Stored Procedure that returns Entities

Tags: stored-procedures, entity-framework-4

I am attempting to execute a stored procedure that returns data with exactly the same columns as that of a table Entity I have in my project. I set the 'Returns a Collection Of' property in the 'Add Function Import' dialog to my entity type.

I get a NullReferenceException error when executing the stored procedure and on further digging it seems that it is because the 'EntityKey' property is missing. Is there anything I can do to tell it to ignore those special properties of the Entity?

I already have a partial class for that entity with '[ScaffoldColumn(false)]' but that doesn't seem to matter.

Cheers,
Nick

EDIT:

Here is the stack trace:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>      System.Data.EntityKey.AddHashValue(Int32 hashCode, Object keyValue) +36
>      System.Data.EntityKey.GetHashCode() +7696654
>      System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer`1.GetHashCode(T obj) +23
>      System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key) +70
>      System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value) +17
>      System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.TryGetEntityEntry(EntityKey key, EntityEntry& entry) +111
>      System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly(Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet) +102
>      lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) +460
>      System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper) +170
>      System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext() +84
>      System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +406
>      System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
>      TWAgencySpend.Controllers.ReportsController.Advertising(Nullable`1 agencyId, Nullable`1 businessUnitId) in C:\dasdsd\Controllers\ReportsController.cs:72
>      lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +190
>      System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +51
>      System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +409
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +52
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassd.b__a() +127
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +436
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassf.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__c() +61
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +305
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +830
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +136
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +111
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4() +65
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +44
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult _) +42
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +141
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +54
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8836913
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184

Updated: Here is the item in the SSDL for the function:

```
    <Function Name="GetAgencyReport" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo">
      <Parameter Name="AgencyId" Type="int" Mode="In" />
      <Parameter Name="Year" Type="int" Mode="In" />
    </Function>
```

and here is the call:

```
reportsViewModel.AgencyReportData = twAgencySpendEntities.GetAgencyReport(agencyId.Value, 2010).ToList();
```

and here is the key for my Entity:

```
<EntityType Name="AdvertisingData">
  <Key>
    <PropertyRef Name="AgencyId" />
    <PropertyRef Name="BusinessUnitId" />
    <PropertyRef Name="Month" />
    <PropertyRef Name="Year" />
  </Key>
  <Property Name="AgencyId" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
  <Property Name="BusinessUnitId" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
  <Property Name="Month" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
  <Property Name="Year" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
  ...
```

Comment: Do you have a piece of the code? Because most of the time this will lead to a not instantiated object.

Comment: How is the key mapped in EDMX? I.e., what is the `<Key>` value in SSDL for this proc?

Comment: `FunctionImport` is CSDL, not SSDL. The SSDL element is `Function`, and the `Key` element is on the corresponding entity in CSDL -- in your case, `AdvertisingData`. The function must return the unique key.

Comment: Updated to show the Function and Key elements in the EDMX. This is more to do with the EntityKey property though isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the reason why the framework is trying to dereference the `EntityKey` is that the `MergeOption` property for your query is set to `AppendOnly`. No great surprise there, as `AppendOnly`is the default. With `AppendOnly`, the framework will examine every entity loaded into memory and try to fixup the references such that:

1. The same entity can never be loaded into memory twice in two different locations, even if you query it from the database twice.
2. Any entity which refers to that entity will always point at the same reference.

Entities are identified via the `EntityKey` property, which accounts for the reference to this property in the call stack you post.

So one option would be to change the `MergeOption` on the query you're running to `NoTracking`. This is often the best choice for a read-only query. Just be advised that the entities returned cannot be used as referenced entities when you are editing other entities.

The other option would be to figure out why the `EntityKey` is null. I still don't see the full EDMX for your proc, but the key in your CSDL is sufficiently complex that I presume it just doesn't map to the entity quite right, so the EF cannot figure out how to construct the correct `EntityKey` while it is materializing entities from your proc.

Comment: I was getting this exception as well. My problem was that I changed a column in the database to allow nulls. I had a View in my data model that was returning this column. The column in the view had "Entity Key" set to true.  Since this column now allows nulls, I had to change "Entity Key" to false, as it can no longer be used to generate a unique key for this entity because it allows nulls.